# Is merging mandatory in Git?

Tags: git

I use SVN for a while now. But I just use checkout, update and commit, since I just need a backup with history.

I am trying Git now in a new project. Here is what I did:

- Created a repository in Bitbucket.
- Git clone to my machine.
- Created a couple of files.
- Git commit -a.
- Git push.

All fine. I checked Bitbucket and the files were there. That was yesterday. Today I did:

- Added some more files.
- Git commit -a.
- Git push.

And I got an error message. I didn't save it, but it said something about fast-forward. For some reason I couldn't push my commit to the repository. I did several fetches, commits and pushes and got the same error when pushing. Then I did a pull, which as far as I know is a fetch followed by a merge, then a push and it worked (kinda). My repository log looks like this now:

```
commit ef6b0e51c8278ef15d1d84770a56929f7c30cc63
Merge: 15d482c ab3938a
Author: xxx
Date:   Wed Jan 25 04:25:39 2012 -0200

    Merge branch 'master' of bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx

commit 15d482c0bd2e9b894afd779520dbfdbad7f43616
Author: xxx
Date:   Tue Jan 24 03:50:43 2012 -0200

    xxx

commit ab3938aaacb089f1c4f3bdbb8d843a105991f776
Author: xxx
Date:   Tue Jan 24 03:50:43 2012 -0200

    xxx
```

This is strange. The first commit is right. It was done yesterday. But the second should have today's date. But it has the exact same date as yesterday's, up to the seconds. And there is a third commit, which is just the merging, with today's date.

Is this the way it is supposed to be? Or did I do something wrong? Do I have to merge between a commit and a push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I checked "Amend Last Commit" on the second commit. So, basically I did:

- Create repository on Bitbucket.
- Clone.
- Add file1.
- Commit.
- Push.
- Add file2.
- Commit --amend
- Push.

The error I got was:

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master

To git@bitbucket.org:xxx/test_repo.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:xxx/test_repo.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried fetch and merge. Still couldn't push. I had to do a pull. I got:

```
git.exe pull -v --progress      "origin"

From bitbucket.org:xxx/test_repo
= [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
Success
```

Then I could push.

Amending a commit that had already been pushed was the problem. That is why both commits have the same date.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you've answered your own question, feel free to select it as the answer to help future users who turn this up in a search.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't push because it's not a fast-forward update, then that means that someone pushed commits to bitbucket. A fast-forward update is an update from a previous commit in the current commit's history, ie. You aren't doing a merge, you are simply fast-forwarding time.

Pull will do a `git fetch` and then a `git merge`, which may or may not result in an actual merge, git will do a fast-forward by default if at all possible.

From your log above, there was an actual merge, so we're back to square one. Somehow some extra commits made their way into your bitbucket repository. Did you perhaps do some edits online?

As to your question about requiring a merge, no you do not *need* to do a merge. You do need to resolve the fork though. You can do this in one of two ways. You can either do a merge, or you can do what is termed a rebase. Basically what git does when you do a rebase is reapply the diffs of your commits to the end of the alternate history. This creates the illusion that you did your new work directly on top of the other new work. Git preserves author and commit dates, so the history can get a little non-linear if you take to rebasing a lot, however some people prefer the single-line history. You can easily do a rebase by using `git pull --rebase`

Comment: There is no other user. Only I use this repository. And if some other user added a commit, it should show on the log, right?

Comment: @user1170442: Try using a graphical log like gitk, that might help clarify exactly what happened. If there's a merge commit with only a single parent, then check your value for `merge.ff` with `git config merge.ff`. If it is `false` then git forces a merge commit on fastwards: http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html

Comment: If your merge commit has two parents, then *something* has managed to get a commit into your remote repo somehow. Again, gitk should help locate exactly what and when/who.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing is only possible, if the pushed branch can be merged on the pushed onto branch using a `fast-forward` merge, meaning that the current head of the remote branch must be part of your local branches history. If you don't have the newest version of the remote branch merged into your local branch the push will fail (this is the same as with svn, where you can't commit if your local version isn't recent).

Therefore it seems as if there was a commit pushed to that branch (on the remote repo) between you pushing yesterday and you trying to push today, though with the informations given I couldn't say where it comes from.

So if you work on a branch alone (and only from one location), you can typically get away with simply commiting and pushing, otherwise you might need to use `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or simply `git pull`) to get the most recent version of the remote branch into your own, before you can push it.

Comment: There is no other user. Only I use this repository.

Comment: @user1170442: Well I can only tell you that somehow there was a difference between the local and the global history. There is not really enough info to say why they differed

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some other user added a commit to your BitBucket repository. What you describe is exactly what would happen if your push failed with a message that git cannot fast forward.

Clearly that must have happened, because git log reports there was *something* to merge in ef6b0e5.

And you found the solution: you had to pull (fetch and merge the upstream change into your branch) from the Bitbucket repo before git would allow you to push your changes.

Comment: There is no other user. Only I use this repository. And if some other user added a commit, it should show on the log, right?

Comment: Also, Bitbucked said about commit ef6b0e5:
    
    No files were affected. This commit was a merge between 15d482c0bd2e and ab3938aaacb0.

Comment: "Somehow some extra commits made their way into your bitbucket repository" as @Matthew said. It may not have been another user. Figuring out how *that* happened would probably shed some light on why you had to pull before you could push. btw it might be helpful to use the --graph option to git log, to show you how the branches evolved.